# videocapture opencv (ubuntu 13.10, opencv 2.4.8)

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg, video-capture

when i tried to work with a video file i can't seem to open the file
when i test on isOpen() it gives me thats it did not open

what did i already check:

1. videofile working and in correct path
2. rebooting
3. reinstalling ffmpeg (with diferent configurations)

my code:

```
VideoCapture readVideo;
    readVideo.open(argv[1]);
    Mat frame;
    if(!readVideo.isOpened()){
        fprintf(stderr,"video niet geladen 0 \n");
        return 2;
    }
```

Example of the file i give in argv[1]:
out.avi (mpeg4 codex)
it works on someone elses setup so i know its not the code

Comment: Could you please give an example of what do you pass to argv[1]?

Comment: How about give the complete path of out.avi to your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to be with the installation of the ffmpeg that wasn't compleetly linked to the instalation of opencv, installed bouth again and worked like a charm